# Why doesn't L'hopitals Rule work for $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{x+ \sin x}{x+ 2 \sin x}$?

Tags: limits

This is how I would evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x+ \sin x}{x+ 2 \sin x}$

$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x \left( 1+ \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)}{x \left(1+ 2 \cdot \frac{ \sin x}{x} \right)}$

$= \dfrac{1+0}{1+2 \cdot 0} = 1$

But now applying L'hopitals Rule, I get

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1+ \cos x}{1+ 2 \cos x}$

Since $\cos x $ just oscillates between $[-1,1]$ I think we can  conclude the limit doesn't exist.

What is going on here?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342202/515527 . This is a question raised quite frequently.

Comment: This is also explained on the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Requirement_that_the_limit_exist) where there is a simpler example such as $(x + \cos x)/x$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366382/why-do-we-need-to-check-for-more-than-frac-infty-infty-or-frac00-w)

Answer (score 15):

L'Hospital's rule contains an assumption that $\lim_{x \to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists, which is not true in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, students often forget the hypotheses for a result when they try to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

Because your function doesn't satisfy the hypothesis. If you are studing the limit $x\to c$, in order to apply the theorem the function $g=x+2\sin x$ must be differentiable and $g'(x)\ne 0$ in an open interval containing $c$, except in $c$. That means that you need a set (M,+\infty) where $g' \ne 0$. But $g'(x)=0$ $\forall x=-\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$, so it doesn't exists a set like that.

Comment: The explanation is true and thus +1, yet the OP's question seems to point towards the fact that he forgot that L'Hospital's Rule applies in one direction only. Observe that if the denominator was $\;3x+2\sin x\;$ then L'Hospital *is appliable*...yet it still wouldn't help as the limit of the quotient of the derivatives doesn't exist ...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!